# What's the best way to connect to multiple URLs concurrently with perl

Tags: perl, multitasking, lwp

I have a perl script that checks a database for internal API call requests.

When it sees one, it uses LWP to call the API as requested.

The problem is that sometimes the requests can take a while to complete and the other requests are queued behind them. I am trying to work out the best way to prevent this situation.

The script is relatively simple. I have looked briefly at POE and AnyEvent, but haven't been able to find any tutorials that help me understand how they would be used in this context. It seems like they are primarily designed for much more complicated situations.

Over simplified, my half-pseudo code is:

```
while (1) {
    $url=getNextRequestFromDB();
    if ($url ne "") {
        $request = new HTTP::Request('GET', $url);
        my $response = $ua->request($request);
        logResponse($response);
    }
    else {
        sleep(5);
    }
}
```

I don't mind if the response isn't logged, or (preferably) if it is logged separately.

Answer (score 2):

The [LWP::Parallel](https://metacpan.org/pod/LWP::Parallel) CPAN module match the requirements you are looking for. It takes a list of URLs (supports http, ftp and file URLs), connect them in parallel, and then wait for the results.

Comment: This looks interesting, but I'm not sure it would help here. For example, if I got 4 requests on loop 1 and request #1 took 5 minutes, then it's still 5 minutes before loop 2 starts, so if another request was entered just after the code call to `$pua->wait`, it would still be stuck until the current 4 requests are done.

Answer (score 1):

To parallelize long-running operations in perl programs, use fork() or a threading library.

A fork is a subprocess which initially inherits an own copy of all the program's state and then is independed. Each fork needs an own DB connection.

fork() returns the newly created child processes id when you are in the PARENT copy of the program and false when you are in the child.

```
# create 10 children

my @children;

for ( my $count = 1; $count <= 10; $count++) {
        my $pid = fork();
        if ($pid) {
        # you are in the parent process
        # print "child has $pid, parent $$\n";
        push(@children, $pid);
        } elsif ($pid == 0) {
                  # You are in the child
                while (1) {
                  ## Connect to the DB
                  ## fetch an api request
                  ## last if $no_request_left
                  ## run an api request
                }
                ## disconnect from DB
                ## cleanup whatever needs to be done, then exit
                exit 0;
        } else {
                die "couldnt fork: $!\n";
        }



}

foreach (@children) {
        my $tmp = waitpid($_, 0);
         print "pid $tmp found no more requests and exited\n";

}

print "Main ends here\n";
```

Comment: If I understand it correctly, you have here 10 forks each running my whole process. Couldn't the db connect be moved out of the fork so that each time it finds a request (instead of the for loop in your example), it forks to do the API call and then logs the response and exits? Then there's no need for more DB connections.

Comment: That won't work. Fork provides child processes which need their own DB connection. If you need to share a DB connection among children, you either need to have the connection in the parent and implement inter-process communication with the parent for all requests or use threading instead. A forked DB connection usually gets stale.

Comment: Addendum: You can redesign the program for this workflow: Have the parent do all the DB stuff, fetch an api call or a reasonably short list/array of calls from DB, create a child, fetch next batch, create next child. Each child would process its list and then terminate.

Comment: I am confused! My thought would be to have the child *only* do the LWP call, having been given the URL from the DB by the parent. The child would have to do nothing more than make the LWP call, log the response and exit, hence no DB connection needed for the child.

Comment: I tried this and it worked, although the parent loses connection to mysql after forking, but that's no big deal, I just reconnect in the parent.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [Mojo::UserAgent](http://mojolicio.us/perldoc/Mojo/UserAgent). They have examples of concurrent requests inside the linked documentation.